# Solve sudoku using Grover's algorithm

Tags: qiskit, programming, grovers-algorithm, applications

[The Qiskit tutorial](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/grover.html#5.-Solving-Sudoku-using-Grover%27s-Algorithm-) shows the application of Grover's Algorithm to solve a 2x2 sudoku. However, I don't understand how why its diffuser works as intended. Precisely, why the control bit is on a "variable" qubit (labeled as "v") rather than on the auxiliary qubit (labeled as "out_0")?

```
var_qubits = QuantumRegister(4, name='v')
clause_qubits = QuantumRegister(4, name='c')
output_qubit = QuantumRegister(1, name='out')
cbits = ClassicalRegister(4, name='cbits')
qc = QuantumCircuit(var_qubits, clause_qubits, output_qubit, cbits)

def sudoku_oracle(qc, clause_list, clause_qubits):
# Compute clauses
    i = 0
    for clause in clause_list:
       XOR(qc, clause[0], clause[1], clause_qubits[I])
       i += 1

# Flip 'output' bit if all clauses are satisfied
    qc.mct(clause_qubits, output_qubit)

# Uncompute clauses to reset clause-checking bits to 0
    i = 0
    for clause in clause_list:
        XOR(qc, clause[0], clause[1], clause_qubits[I])
        i += 1

sudoku_oracle(qc, clause_list, clause_qubits)
qc.draw()

Define difusser:
def diffuser(nqubits):
    qc = QuantumCircuit(nqubits)
# Apply transformation |s> -> |00..0> (H-gates)
    for qubit in range(nqubits):
        qc.h(qubit)
# Apply transformation |00..0> -> |11..1> (X-gates)
    for qubit in range(nqubits):
        qc.x(qubit) 
# Do multi-controlled-Z gate
    qc.h(nqubits-1)
    qc.mct(list(range(nqubits-1)), nqubits-1)  # multi-controlled-toffoli
    qc.h(nqubits-1)
# Apply transformation |11..1> -> |00..0>
    for qubit in range(nqubits):
       qc.x(qubit)
# Apply transformation |00..0> -> |s>
    for qubit in range(nqubits):
       qc.h(qubit)
# We will return the diffuser as a gate
    U_s = qc.to_gate()
    U_s.name = "U$_s$"
    return U_s

#Put everything together
# Initialize 'out0' in state |->
qc.initialize([1, -1]/np.sqrt(2), output_qubit)

# Initialize qubits in state |s>
qc.h(var_qubits)
qc.barrier()  # for visual separation

## First Iteration
# Apply our oracle
sudoku_oracle(qc, clause_list, clause_qubits)
qc.barrier()  # for visual separation
# Apply our diffuser
qc.append(diffuser(4), [0,1,2,3])

## Second Iteration
sudoku_oracle(qc, clause_list, clause_qubits)
qc.barrier()  # for visual separation
# Apply our diffuser
qc.append(diffuser(4), [0,1,2,3])

# Measure the variable qubits
qc.measure(var_qubits, cbits)

qc.draw(fold=-1)
```

The whole circuit looks like this:[image]

The diffuser (U_s) looks like this:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two important things to notice:

1. Notice that the multi-controlled Toffoli has its target qubit surrounded by H gates.  This means we actually have a multi-controlled Z gate..
2. A multi-controlled Z gate has the unusual property that it doesn't distinguish between its target qubit and its control qubits.  If you look at:

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.cz(0, 1)
circ.draw('latex')
```

you'd see the printed circuit doesn't even bother distinguishing between the control and the target.

The net effect of the control Z is that it maps $|1111\rangle$ to $-|1111\rangle$.

Since the entire control-Z is surrounded by a wall of X's on both sides, the total effect of both is that $|0000\rangle$ is mapped to $-|0000\rangle$

---

Update:

I confirmed that Qiskit also prints multi-control Z gates the same way it handles single-control Z gates: no qubit is distinguished as the target.

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(4)
circ.append(ZGate().control(3), [0, 1, 2, 3])
x = circ.draw('text')

q_0: ─■─
      │ 
q_1: ─■─
      │ 
q_2: ─■─
      │ 
q_3: ─■─
```

Your confusion is from the fact that the text chose to implement the controlled-Z gate by way of a controlled-X gate.  One of the qubits had to be picked, arbitrarily, to be the target.